# Inputting a separate hyphenation file

Tags: expansion, input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{english.yp}
    hom-ony-mous
    gene-ral-ly
\end{filecontents*}{english.yp}

\hyphenation{
    \input english.yp
}

\begin{document}
spinach.
\end{document}
```

This does not compile, (but does if I move `\hyphenation{` and `}` in the first and last lines of the file.)  Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTeX implementation of `\input` is not expandable in order to allow a test for braces. However, `\hyphenation` requires an argument which fully expands to text. You therefore have to use the underlying primitive

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{english.yp}
    hom-ony-mous
    gene-ral-ly
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\hyphenation{
    \@@input english.yp
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
spinach.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this example turned out to be too minimal. Posting another.